# Extract words that begin with the same 4 letters

Tags: python

I'm focusing on studying a language with just the first 2,000 common words ( that are in a file of 20,000 words) with their derivatives that are not in first 2,000 words list.

**We have a text file of 20,000 words:**

```
voila  
trouver  
passé  
.....  
passe  
.....  
passer  
.....  
trouve  
.....
```

**We want to extract words that begin with the same `4 letters`, so that the output:**

```
trouver trouve  
passé passe passer  
.....
```

(Or to anything similar)

Comment: hint: look for `str.startswith()`

Comment: if i am not wrong, you asked the same question yesterday. And we asked you to share what you tried. I still don't see any code from you

Comment: I'm focusing on studying a language with just the first 2,000 common words ( that are in a file of 20,000 words) with their derivatives that are not in first 2,000 words list. and I don't have any code with me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this

````
words = list(open("test.txt", "r"))
with open("same_word.txt", "a") as myfile:
    for word in words:
        find_word = word.strip()
        for word in words:
            word = word.strip()
            if word == find_word:
                pass
            elif word.startswith(find_word[:4]):
                myfile.write(word+"\n")
```
````

Comment: Thank you. Can you add a new text file output for the results?

Comment: sure, now the words are appended to file called same_word.txt